# The following classes could not be instantiated:com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView(Open Class, Show Error Log)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

this is my xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.interadd.MainActivity" >


            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             ads:adSize="BANNER"
                             ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2961758853938686/9050318854"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

this is my mainfest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.interadd"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is my java file

```
package com.example.interadd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I am fed up now I have tried to add ads in my app but failed to do it I have given my 100% but don't completed my project I have added google services also to my app but it always give an error message The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
I tried to download new eclipse but I found the same error here also
I hope I be getting my project done here 
thank you

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but are you sure that you are referencing the correct path to that file?

Comment: Yes..i have tried everything brother but failed...it sucks now..